# Boqueio de execução SQL enquanto executo outro programa em transação

Tags: c#, sql-server, transações

Criei um programa que acessa minha base de dados em transação  READ UNCOMMITED.

```
_oConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, _transactionName);
```

Tudo que é executado dentro dessa transação funciona normalmente.
Porém, quando eu abro o SQL Server Managment Stdio e tento executar comandos de ***select, update ou delete***
(que já foram executados anteriomente no programa executando em transação) o SQL Server Managment Studio fica
travado e só executa o comando quando eu fecho a aplicação.

Abaixo, o script de criação do meu Banco de Dados.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [meu_banco]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'meu_banco', FILENAME = N'D:\caminho\meu_banco.mdf' , SIZE = 27200KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'meu_banco_log', FILENAME = N'D:\caminho\meu_banco.ldf' , SIZE = 22144KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [meu_banco].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'disable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO

USE [meu_banco]
GO

EXEC [meu_banco].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'extendpropertyA', @value=N'valorA' 
GO

EXEC [meu_banco].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'extendpropertyB', @value=N'valorB' 
GO

EXEC [meu_banco].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'extendpropertB', @value=N'valorC' 
GO

EXEC [meu_banco].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'extendpropertC', @value=N'valorD' 
GO

EXEC [meu_banco].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'extendpropertD', @value=N'valorE' 
GO

USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [meu_banco] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro se você está dando commit ou rollback na transação. Pode ser que o arquivo esteja em lock e daí o outro sistema, no caso o visual studio, não está conseguindo acessar.
Experimente usar o commit e fechar a conexão.

A construção clássica é:

```cs
var transaction = _oConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, _transactionName);

try
{

    transaction.commit();
}
catch( Exception e)
{
    transaction.roolback();
}
finally
{
  if (_oConn.State != State.Closed)
  {
      _oConn.close();
  }
  _oConn.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Estou fazendo rollback. Indepedente do que ocorrer, o programa em C# sempre deve realizar roolback. É uma das regras desse programa.

Os outros programas (como, por exemplo, o SQL Server managment studio) que acessam a mesma base de dados estão executando fora de transação.

Comment: Vai ser dificil ajudar numa situação onde "Indepedente do que ocorrer, o programa em C# sempre deve realizar roolback".. se ele sempre tem que dar roolback, meu amigo.. acho que seu programa não devia participar dessa existência. Boa sorte!!! kkkkk